# dynamic style of a class Angular ts

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 9, have any ways to dynamic css of a class in component?

```
.stick-menu{
  transform: translate(10px,20px);
}
```

I want dynamic poisition of x and y above, example to

```
.stick-menu{
  transform: translate(20px,30px);
}
```

but not using ngclass or ngstyle, Just change in class and apply to all element
thanks

Comment: try do add `!important` to at the end of the code.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi is not about the css bro

Comment: Can you draw a simple illustration or something else to make it more clear.
You want to change the stylesheet based on the propertie of a element?
If you have not hav a lot of elements you can use property binding. but it's not clear to me what you want to do

Comment: By "dynamic" do you mean you want to use TS values into CSS properties ?

Comment: @Emilien yes, I want change value of a class's attribute by manual. But not use ngStyle or style.tranform because this can only change one and not global

Answer (score 1):

To element you want the css to be applied

```
[style.transform]="getTranform"
```

and in the component, you can specify getTranform function to return the translated location that you want by

```
get getTranform(){
    return `translate(${this.val}px,${this.val}px)`;
}
```